Windows Server 2019: Entries are being erased automatically from Windows Credential Manager, how can I figure out who/what is causing this?
I am running Windows Server 2019 version 1809 build 17763.5936. I am using Windows Credential Manager to securely store some login information in the Generic Credentials section which is utilized by some automation scripts. A few weeks ago, these entries started getting erased. At first it seemed like somebody made a one-off mistake, but after restoring the missing credentials from backup, it happens again and again. I suspect it is some sort of automated process occurring on our network, this will happen multiple times during a workday causing our automated scripts to fail for invalid credentials until somebody manually restores the backup of Windows Credential Manager.
I am trying to figure out how to capture in Windows Event Manager when this is happening and who/what is doing it. By default, accessing/modifying/deleting Credentials Manager entries isn't logged.
I asked ChatGPT to help me diagnose this issue and went through a few different troubleshooting steps, but it still seems that either the information I'm looking for is not being captured and logged, or if it is, I'm not understanding what I'm looking at.
Troubleshooting steps tried so far: Step 1: Enable Auditing of Object Access
Open Local Group Policy Editor:
Press Win + R, type gpedit.msc, and press Enter.
Navigate to Audit Policy:
Go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy.
Enable Auditing for Object Access:
Double-click on Audit Object Access.
Check both Success and Failure boxes to log both successful and unsuccessful access attempts.
Click OK.
Step 2: Set Auditing on the Credential Manager Folder
Locate the Credential Manager File:
The credentials are stored in C:\Users<Your Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials.
Set Auditing on the Folder:
Right-click on the Credentials folder and select Properties.
Go to the Security tab and click on Advanced.
Go to the Auditing tab and click on Add.
Click on Select a Principal, type Everyone, and click OK.
In the Type dropdown, select All.
Under Access, select the types of access you want to audit (usually, all boxes should be checked).
Click OK to apply the changes.
Step 3: Monitor Events in Event Viewer
Now that auditing is enabled, you can monitor related events in the Event Viewer:
Open Event Viewer:
Press Win + R, type eventvwr.msc, and press Enter.
Navigate to Security Logs:
Go to Windows Logs > Security.
Filter the Events:
Right-click on Security and choose Filter Current Log.
Set Event ID to 4663 (Object Access) and click OK.
This will filter the log to show you only the events related to object access, including credential access.
(at this point, Event Viewer still wasn't showing anything when I created/deleted a test Credentials Manager entry)
Step 1: Enable Auditing for Registry Access
Windows stores most of the "Generic Credentials" in the Windows Registry. Therefore, we need to enable auditing for registry access.
Open Local Group Policy Editor:
Press Win + R, type gpedit.msc, and press Enter.
Navigate to Audit Policy:
Go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object > Object Access.
Enable Auditing for Registry Object Access:
Double-click Audit Registry.
Check both Success and Failure boxes to log both successful and unsuccessful registry accesses.
Click OK.
Step 2: Set Auditing on the Relevant Registry Keys
The Generic Credentials are stored in the following registry path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\CACHE\NL$1 (and other similar keys)
We need to set up auditing on this registry key:
Open the Registry Editor:
Press Win + R, type regedit, and press Enter.
Navigate to the Relevant Key:
Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\CACHE.
Set Auditing on the Registry Key:
Right-click on the CACHE key and select Permissions.
Click on Advanced.
Go to the Auditing tab and click on Add.
Click on Select a Principal, type Everyone, and click OK.
Set Type to All and under Access, check the boxes for the actions you want to audit (such as Query Value, Set Value, Create Subkey, etc.).
Click OK to apply.
Step 3: Monitor Events in Event Viewer
Now that you've set up auditing for registry changes:
Open Event Viewer:
Press Win + R, type eventvwr.msc, and press Enter.
Navigate to Security Logs:
Go to Windows Logs > Security.
Filter the Events:
Right-click on Security and choose Filter Current Log.
Look for Event IDs 4656 (Handle to an object was requested) and 4663 (An attempt was made to access an object) to track registry accesses.
Step 4: Analyze the Logs
Look for events with Registry Key paths related to CACHE\NL$ and observe the user or process involved in creating, modifying, or deleting these keys.
This method will give you detailed logs related to the creation, modification, or deletion of Generic Credentials in the Windows Credential Manager.
Step 1: Accessing the SECURITY Hive
Use the psexec Utility:
Download the PsExec utility from the Microsoft Sysinternals website.
Extract the psexec executable to a location on your system.
Open a Command Prompt with SYSTEM Privileges:
Open a command prompt as Administrator.
Navigate to the directory where you extracted psexec.
Run the following command to open a command prompt with SYSTEM privileges:
bash

psexec -i -s cmd.exe

This will open a new command prompt window running under the SYSTEM account.

Open Registry Editor with SYSTEM Privileges:
In the SYSTEM command prompt, type regedit and press Enter.
This will open the Registry Editor with SYSTEM privileges.
Step 2: Navigating to the CACHE Key
In the SYSTEM-privileged Registry Editor:
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY.
Now, you should see the CACHE subkey available under SECURITY.
Set Auditing on the CACHE Registry Key:
Follow the same instructions as before to set up auditing on the CACHE key.
Right-click on the CACHE key, select Permissions, then Advanced, and go to the Auditing tab.
Step 3: Monitor Events in Event Viewer
After setting up auditing, you can monitor the relevant registry events as described previously using the Event Viewer.
This method should allow you to access the SECURITY hive and set up the necessary auditing to track changes to the Generic Credentials in Credential Manager. If you're not comfortable using psexec, you might want to consult with a system administrator for assistance.
(at this point, I expanded the monitoring to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY and all children objects. Test entries being created/deleted in Credentials Manager still not showing up)
